# Getting a property value from a Generically typed object and casting it in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a generic property on a class like this:

```
export class OStore<E> {
...
    /**
     * Start keys and values
     * passed in via constructor.
     */
    public S!: E
```

And I need to get a value like this:

```
const ovr:ObsValueReset = this.S[k] as ObsValueReset
```

But it creates this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.ts(7053)

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `ObsValueReset `? and `this` refers to what? we need some more code to solve the problem

Comment: `ObsValueReset` is an interface for the value keyed by the `k` key ... So `S` is just an object ... with a generic type interface ... all the keys are strings and all the values are of type `ObsValueReset` ... which could be replaced with any interface really ... `this` is an instance of `OStore<E>` ...

Comment: This is the entire class ... I'm rewriting it ... https://github.com/fireflysemantics/slice/blob/master/projects/slice/src/lib/OStore.ts

Comment: Where are you specifying what `E` is for your `OStore<E>`?

Comment: based on your comment `E` must extends the `ObsValueReset` yes? like this `OStore<E extends ObsValueReset>`

Comment: Hmmm ... I tried that ... It's not working .... So all the property values of `E` are of type `ObsValueReset` ... but that gives me an idea ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create this interface:

```
interface KeyObsValueReset {
    [key: string]: ObsValueReset
}
```

Then extend the generic type with it:

```
export class OStore<E extends KeyObsValueReset> {
```

Now it should work.